# $p$-adic series bounded if and only if it has finitely many zeros

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, p-adic-hodge-theory, non-archimedean-fields

Let $L\subseteq\mathbb{C}_p$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $r$ be a positive real number, and $f$ be a series $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_nz^n$ convergent in $D= \{x\in \mathbb{C}_p|0<v(x)\leq r \}$ where $a_n$ are elements in $L$. Then I want to know if the following are equivalent.

(1) $f$ is a bounded function in the metric of $\mathbb{C}_p$

(2) $f$ only has finitely many zeros in $D$

(3) the set $\{\lvert a_n\rvert\}$ is bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$(in the Euclid metric)

Symbols: $\lvert a_n\rvert\mathrel{:=}p^{-v(a_n)}$ and $v$ is the valuation of $\mathbb{C}_p$ extended by the valuation on $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Motivations: I want to use this to prove some properties of the Robba ring over $L$, e.g., $\varepsilon^\dagger$ is a field.

Thanks!

Comment: "only finite zeros" meaning only *finitely many* zeros?

Comment: And $L$ is a subset, not an element, of ${\bf C}_p$, right? and the $a_n$ are in $L$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I will edit my question right now!

Comment: $L$ is still an element of ${\bf C}_p$?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar $D=\{x: p^{-r}\leq|x|<1\}$, and $f$ is a bounded function when we regard $f$ as a function over $D$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Robba ring.  Is it as in Definition 2.5.3 of [Kedlaya - Finiteness of rigid cohomology with coefficients](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208027)?  Where is $\varepsilon^\dagger$ defined?

Comment: @LSpice  You can see Berger's IHP note. I have heared from my adviser that there are two ways to define the Robba ring $R$ over $L$ and it is not so easy to prove the two definitions coincident. And I know one definition is that $R:=\bigcup_{r>0}L(o,r]$ and $L(o,r]$ is consisted of all $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}a_nx^n$ for $a_n\in L$ which is convergent on $\{x\in\mathbb{C}_p| 0<|x|\leq r\}$

Comment: @LSpice And the ring $\varepsilon^\dagger$ is defined as the subring of $R$ consisted of all series whose coefficients are bounded, i.e. $\{|a_n|,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is bounded in the metric of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2) and (3) are equivalent. This is corollary 3.3 in Laurent Berger's IHP course notes [Galois representations and $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-modules](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.berger/autrestextes/CoursIHP2010.pdf) in 2010. In the same way, we can prove (1) and (3) are equivalent (in one direction, convergence is used).

Comment: How does your cited proof of equivalence square with @GeraldEdgar's [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/a/346494)?

Comment: I don’t think it is a counterexample, since the domain of convergence of his series is clearly $\{z\in\Bbb C_p:v(z)>1/2\}$, as @DrorSpeiser has, in essence, pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

**Example**
Take $\mathbb Q_3$ itself.  Consider
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-k} z^{2k}.
$$
($a_n = 0$ when $n < 0$ or $n$ is odd.)  Now if $|z|<1$, then $|z| \le 3^{-1}$ and
$$
\big|3^{-k} z^{2k}\big| \le 3^k 3^{-2k} \to 0
$$
so $f$ converges on $\{z\;:\; |z|<1\}$.  But
$$
\big|a_{2k}\big| = \big|3^{-k}\big| = 3^k,
$$
and $\{|a_n|\}$ is not bounded.  Also
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{1-3z^2} .
$$
Thus $f$ has no zeros in $D$.  And when $z \in D$ we have $|z|\le 3^{-1}$ so
$|z^2| \le 3^{-2}$ so $|3z^2| \le 3^{-3}$, so $|1-3z^3| = 1$ and therefore $|f(z)| = 1$ on $D$. Thus $f$ is bounded on $D$.

---

OK, but (note Dror's comment) what about boundedness on $\{z \in \mathbb C_3\;:\; 0<|z| < 1\}$?  There are $z \in \mathbb C_3$ with $3^{-1/2}<|z|<1$, and for such $z$ we have
$$
\big|3^{-k} z^{2k}\big| = 3^k |z|^{2k} > 3^{-k} (3^{-1/2})^{2k} > 1
$$
so the series does not converge.

---

Let's try another one.
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-k} z^{3^k}
$$
Let $a_n \in \mathbb Q_3$ so that $a_{3^k} = 3^{-k}$ for subscripts of the form $3^k$ and zero otherwise.  Let $|z|<1$. Then is it true that $|z| = 3^r$ for some $r \in\mathbb Q$, $r < 0$ ??  If so,
$$
\big| a_{3^k} z^{3^k}\big| = \big|3^{-k} z^{3^k}\big| = 3^k (3^r)^{3^k}
= 3^{k+3^k r} \to 0
$$
and we get convergence.

But maybe that $|z| = 3^r$ is only for the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_3$, not the metric closure $\mathbb C_3$ if it??

Comment: Your answer wrote that if $|z|<1$, then $|z|<3^{-1}$?

Comment: @Sssss, it says that if $\lvert z\rvert < 1$ then $\lvert z\rvert \le 3^{-1}$, which is true (in $\mathbb Q_3$).

Comment: For this function there is no positive $r$ such that the function converges on $\{x\in\mathbb{C}_p :\ 0<v(x) \le r\}$.

Comment: So you claim it does not converge on $\{x\;:\; 0 < v(x) \le 1\}=\{x\;:\; 3^{-1}\le |x| < 1\}$ ??

Comment: I may be terminally confused, but the annulus $D$ was defined as the set of all $\Bbb C_p$-points satisfying the inequalities. Seems to me that $3^{1/4}$ is in your annulus, and the series doesn’t converge there.

Comment: Yeah, @GeraldEdgar. Your last example is interesting. It is the logarithm of a formal group of height one defined over $\Bbb Z_3$, even $\Bbb Z_3$-isomorphic to the multiplicative formal group. it is convergent on the (open) unit disk in $\Bbb C_3$, has infinitely many zeros there, and is unbounded as a function on the open disk.

Comment: The absoute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ is a function $\mathbb{Q}_3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$(if we normalized), so if $|z|<1$ then $|z|<\frac{1}{3}$ can't be true... Thanks all the same  for your thinking and your answers!

Comment: In the notation of the OP, the "valuation" $v : \mathbb Q_p\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb Z$ has integer values, but in the notation in your question, the "absolute value" is $|x| = p^{-v(x)}$ which has values only powers of $p$.  That is where the $3^{-1}$ comes from.